# F#: Recursive Functions: test whether an element is a member of a given list

Tags: list, recursion, f#, boolean

I'm trying to figure out how to code this.

Implement in F# a function that tests whether an element is a member of a given list. Here is the type I want.

val memberof : ’a * ’a list -> bool when ’a : equality

Here are examples of the function in action.

> memberof 1 [1;2;3];;
>   error FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied
>
> memberof (1,[1;2;3]);;
>   val it : bool = true
>
> memberof (1, []);;
>   val it : bool = false
>
> memberof (1,[2;3;4]);;
>   val it : bool = false

heres what i've put together...

```fs
let rec memberof l =
    match (l:float) with
    | a.Item(l) -> l -> bool + (memberof l)
```

or

```js
let rec memberof l =
    match (l:float list) with
    | [] -> false
    | (a:float)::b -> (a)=(memberof b)->bool
```

Comment: where are the examples from? Because your function does not even have the right signature (and I don't mean the `float` vs the `'a`) - also: is this an exercise? Because if you look in the `List` module you can find what you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let rec memberof (l : float list) (item : float) : bool =
    match l with
    | hd::tl when hd = item -> true
    | hd::tl -> memberof tl item
    | [] -> false
```

or

```
let rec memberof (l : float list) (item : float) : bool =
    match l with
    | hd::tl ->
        if hd = item then
            true
        else
            memberof tl item
    | [] -> false
```

or

```
let rec memberof (l : float list) (item : float) : bool =
     match l with 
     | [] -> false 
     | hd :: tl -> 
         hd = item
         || memberof tl item
```

Test cases

```
let test001 = memberof [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] 0.0    
printfn "test001: %A" test001   

let test002 = memberof [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] 1.0  
printfn "test002: %A" test002   

let test003 = memberof [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] 2.0  
printfn "test003: %A" test003 

let test004 = memberof [1.0; 2.0; 3.0] 3.0  
printfn "test004: %A" test004   

let test005 = memberof [] 0.0    
printfn "test005: %A" test005
```

Which outputs

```
val test001 : bool = false
val test002 : bool = true
val test003 : bool = true
val test004 : bool = true
val test005 : bool = false
```

The problem with

```
let rec memberof l =
    match (l:float list) with
    | [] -> false
    | (a:float)::b -> (a)=(memberof b)->bool
```

is that

```
| (a:float)::b -> (a)=(memberof b)->bool
```

is pulling the list apart correctly with

```
 (a:float)::b
```

however

```
 (a)=(memberof b)->bool
```

is not right.

With recursive functions over a list you want to pull off the head of the list and process the head. Then you want to call the function again, this time passing the tail of the list as the new list variable, e.g.

```
memberof tl item
```

Since this is a [predicate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_(mathematical_logic)), we only need to stop once we reach a desired true or false. In this example when true is found the function can end, so no need to call `memberof` for the remainder of the list.

For the particular signature you requested

> val memberof : item:'a * list:'a list -> bool when 'a : equality

```
let rec memberof ((item : 'a), (list : 'a list)) : bool when 'T : equality =
    match list with
    | hd::tl ->
        if hd = item then
            true
        else
            memberof (item, tl)
    | [] -> false
```